# Automatically redirecting Google form user based on last answer choice

Tags: google-chrome, google-apps-script, google-forms

I am trying to redirect a user to another website if their answer choice was yes on the last question of my google form. I'm not quite sure why it is not working.

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
  var items = form.getItems();
  var lastQuestion = items[items.length - 1];
  var lastAnswer = '';
  if (lastQuestion instanceof FormApp.Item.MultipleChoiceItem) {
    lastAnswer = lastQuestion.asMultipleChoiceItem().getSelectedItems()[0].getValue();
  }
  var url = '';
  if (lastAnswer === 'Yes') {
    url = 'http://www.example.com';
  }

  var html = '<html><script>window.top.location.href="' + url + '"</script></html>';
  var userInterface = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html);
  form.showConfirmationDialog(userInterface);
}
```

Comment: By the time you get the onFormSubmit trigger your answer has already been  submitted.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.